# new FILE doesn't Exist in OS X 10.7

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying the following but getting no file created ( no errors thrown either ) on my iMac OS X 10.7.5

tried different paths and looked at permissions, can easily do -> $ touch myFile1.txt through the console...

If I do create the file by console and run the code the file is detected and exists.

File f = new File("/Users/myname/Documents/myFile1.txt"); will not create one...

Why doesn't this work?

```
     File f = new File("/Users/myname/Documents/myFile1.txt");
     if(f.exists()) {
         System.out.println(f.getName() + " file exists");
     } else {
         System.out.println(f.getName() + " doesn’t exist");
     }
```

Thanks for any help....

Comment: Did you try opening it for writing?

Comment: try {
     
    String content = "This is the content to write into file";
  
                                File file = new File("/Users/myname/Documents/myFile1.txt");
  
    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
     file.createNewFile();
    }
  
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();
  
    System.out.println("Done");
  
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

To actually write this file to disk and hence have it exist....

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing

File f = new File();

only an object of type File is created. It is not creating an actual file.

The Actual file is created when you use

f.createNewFile() function of class File.